# Deleting files in azure account using databricks python code

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks

How to write a pyspark/python code in databricks to delete files older than X days in azure storage account.

Comment: what is the file format? Is it Delta or something else?

Comment: it's better just use built-in retention policy for ADLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-time-based-retention-policy-overview

Comment: Yes Alex. I am aware of that as well as using activities in Azure datafactory we can do. But I wanted to write a code for that. So were seeking help in that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can read your data and use [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) to figure which file(s) needed to delete, aggregate and collect them, then use [`dbutils.fs`](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs) to handle the deletion.

Comment: Yes but using that I only have idea that we can delete as dbutils.fs.rm but I would like to check the age of the csv file and then delete it. So I was looking for that solution.
Thanks.

Comment: I see, pls check my updated answer